# Suppress karma-junit-reporter warnings about Sonarqube

Tags: junit, sonarqube, karma-runner

When I have the junit reporter enabled, my console output is swamped with lines reading:

> WARN [reporter.junit]: Sonarqube may fail to parse this report since the test file was not found at [...]

I understand the reason for this is that my spec names don't conform to the special format but what if I don't care about Sonarqube? Can I just suppress these warnings?